# In Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade (1989), when does this shot of Sean Connery happen?

Tags: indiana-jones, the-last-crusade

I was replaying a Super NES video game titled [Indiana Jones' Greatest Adventures (1994)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones%27_Greatest_Adventures) which has us playing through the stories of the three movies of the (then) trilogy.

When you run out of life, the following Game Over screen is shown, with the face of Sean Connery (portraying Henry Jones Senior., aka. Indy's father in the third movie), as a voice can be heard saying: "I've lost him."

Since every pictures of the game I came across were taken directly from within the movies they came from, I tried searching that face using Google Image to find when it happened in the movie, and I came across this, which isn't exactly like the one from the game but close enough.

[image: A shot with Henry Jones Senior looking at something behind the camera in astonishment. The shot is very similar to the face depicted in the game over screen, but his eyes are looking above instead of facing the screen.]

I tried searching that second image, but the only thing I find is the photo itself.

Does anyone know at which moment during the third movie does this scene happen?

Comment: Can't say for certain in this case, but much of the time publicity shots are seperate from film-footge.

Comment: @JiminyCricket.: or scenes that were cut, no?

Comment: Did you mean "I've losht `im" instead ?  :)

Comment: Irrespective of the actual origin, the shadow placement strongly suggests that it's the same photo but that the eyes have been Photoshopped to look dead forwards.

Comment: @Criggie Nah, I meant: _"I washed him"_

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It appears that isn't a shot taken directly from the theatrical cut of the film itself, but an alternate angle of a shot that appeared at around the 1 hour and 40 minute mark, or possibly a shot of an alternate take of the same scene.

> [image: Image of Sean Connery from "Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade" (1989).]
>
> <sub>*Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade* (1989)</sub>

To provide more context, the shot I'm referring to (shown above) is from the third act of the film, when Henry and the others were in the [Temple of the Sun](https://indianajones.fandom.com/wiki/Temple_of_the_Sun) watching the [Hatay Soldier](https://indianajones.fandom.com/wiki/Hatay_Soldier_in_Temple) walk into the trap where he got his head chopped off.

The image in your question can't have been captured from any scenes much earlier than that in the film, because Henry had his shirt buttoned all the way up and a bow tie on up until the point that he and the others were approaching the Temple of the Sun. And it can't have been captured much later in the film, because Henry was shot in the stomach shortly after that, his hat was taken off, and he isn't shown wearing it again for the rest of the film.

Comment: It looks like you're just a few steps away from 100k rep

Comment: @Clockwork - Yeah. Not sure if it means very much, but it's a nice number to hit.

Comment: I remember some people saying it's the threshold to receive goodies from Stack Exchange. I'm all for goodies (if I actually wanted to get that much reputation that is).

Comment: @Clockwork - For whatever it's worth, I passed 100K over two days ago now, and haven't received any "goodies" from Stack Exchange, or at least none that I've been made aware of. I wasn't expecting (and wasn't promised) anything though, so no complaints here.

Answer (score 24):

While LogicDictates' answer correctly shows where the image itself comes from, the "I've lost him" quote is a from an earlier scene in the film, not from the same scene as the image.

Specifically, it's from the scene where Indiana Jones and [Colonel Vogel](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097576/characters/nm0126250) are fighting on the tank and then it drives off the edge of a cliff into the valley below. Dr. Jones, Sr., Sallah, and Marcus Brody then walk up to the edge of the cliff and look down to see the remains of the tank continuing to tumble and break apart. They all assume Indiana Jones fell to his death with the tank and Col. Vogel and Dr. Jones says this line. As the three are still looking down into the valley below, we see Indiana Jones climb up a large vine and then walk up behind them and look down into the valley with them.

You can see this scene [here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np4OojYGixI). The line is delivered just after the 50 second mark in this clip.